# Multiple Instances of Wordpress Homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, function

Our homepage displays 12 random posts from a specific category using this code:

```
<?php
// The Query
global $wp_query;
query_posts(
array_merge(
array(
'cat' => '4320',
'orderby' => 'rand',
'posts_per_page' => 12
),
$wp_query->query
)
);
?>
```

That works perfectly, but our site is now showing hundreds of duplicates of our homepage.

Site: https://www.newbonuses.com

One of the duplicates xhttps://www.newbonuses.com/page/999 (remove the x)

How do I disable the /page/ for our homepage? Is their something I can add to functions
or modify the existing query?

I can't seem to figure out how to remove that sub-directory.